# iPad disappearing storage after using app store

Tags: ipad, ios

Storage is always a problem for me on my iPad Mini 2 but recently I freed up about 700 MB and then went to download an app. App store made me agree to the new T&C and then when I clicked Get again said I didn't have enough space. Fine. Except now the reported space was 0 MB. I rebooted the iPad with no change. No new items in Manage Storage. Where did my 700 MB go?

Comment: What did you delete? Apps? Photos? Video?

Comment: Mainly apps. Small number of photos.